# Matching filenames containing a particular string in delimited format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a program which makes backups of PostgreSQL databases. The name of each file/backup is like this:

```
prefix + database_name + creation_date + suffix
```

Where `prefix` (which is optional) and `database_name` are edited by the user, `creation_date` is the date when the backup was made and `suffix` can be .dump, .bz2, .gz or .zip.

The problem now is that the program has to give the chance to the user to delete every backup of one particular database, this is, I have to find every file/backup which has the `database_name` in its name.

But I have to take into account that a database's name could be, for example, '01', and this could be a big problem if the `prefix` or the `creation_date` have a '01'... so for this reason I can't just check if `database_name` is in the file's name.

Any idea to solve this? I racked my brains but I have no idea.

Comment: What format does the creation date follow? Is it a fixed YYYY-MM-DD format perhaps?

Comment: Are you able to change the format of the filenames e.g. `prefix_databasename_creationdate.suffix`? This way you would be able to look for a unique separator of your choosing.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I use _ as separator, and date is in YYYYmmdd_hhiiss format, here is an example of a backup name: prefix_dbname_20140409_115239_CEST.dump. I could make the user not to write _ in the prefix, but I can't take control of the database's name.

Comment: If the optional prefix is omitted, would your name be `_dbname_20140409_115239_CEST.dump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string into its parts; a regex can help with that.

For example:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"^([^_]*)_(.*)_(\d{8}_\d{6}_[^_]+\.(?:dump|bz2|gz|zip))$")
```

You could then check if the second group matches the query:

```
>>> regex.search("prefix_dbname_20140409_115239_CEST.dump").groups()
('prefix', 'dbname', '20140409_115239_CEST.dump')
```

So if `regex.search(myfile).groups()[1]` contains your search string, you can delete `myfile`.

**Explanation:**

```
^                      # Start of string
([^_]*)                # Group 1 (prefix): Any number of characters except _
_                      # _
(.*)                   # Group 2 (dbname): Any number of characters
_                      # _
(                      # Group 3 (timestamp/extension):
 \d{8}_\d{6}           # Date_Time
 _[^_]+                # _Timezone
 \.(?:dump|bz2|gz|zip) # .Extension
)                      # End of group 3
$                      # End of string
```